# Erro de referencia no winsock2

Tags: c, windows

Eu estou querendo criar um socket em c com a api do windows winsock2.h mas ao tentar compilar o meu codigo me retorna o seguinte erro

> undefined referrence to WSAStartup
>
> undefined referrence to WSAGetLast
>
> Error error: ld returned 1 exit status

codigo de inicialização do winsock

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Retire esta linha de código

```
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library
```

2) Na IDE CodeBlocks, insira um novo projeto, Coloquei o nome **Sockets**
[image: CodeBlocks]

3) Escolha Console Application e clique em GO

Na janela que aparece clique em Next
e depois escolha a linguagem C
[image: CodeBlocks]

4) Na função main.c coloque seu código sem usar o #pragma

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.");

    return 0;
}
```

5) Clique botão direito do mouse sobre o nome do projeto e escolha Build Options
[image: Build Options]

6) Escolha(Clique) na aba Linker Settings e em Link Libraries clique no botão ADD
[image: Linker Settings]

7) Digite o seguinte: ws2_32 e clique em OK
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

8) Compile e veja que está sem erro agora
[image: compilando socket]

9) Ao executar aparece a mensagem numa boa agora!
Bom Estudo!!!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
OBs: Se for em outra IDE veja como inserir a bliblioteca pois o compilador GCC muitas vezes não reconhece ou considera inclusões de bilbioteca via diretiva #pragma